# Count how many keys are in a list

Tags: elixir

Is there an idiomatic way to calculate how many times appear the key `test` in this list?

```
[%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}]
```

I would define a variable and use `Enum.each` or `for ->` but I know there must be a way to do it more functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Enum.count/2` and `Map.has_key?/2`:

```
iex(1)> list = [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}]
[%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}]
iex(2)> Enum.count(list, &Map.has_key?(&1, "test"))
2
```

As requested in comment below, here's how to count in a list of lists:

```
iex(3)> lists = [list, list, list]
[[%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}],
 [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}],
 [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}]]
iex(4)> lists |> Enum.reduce(0, fn list, acc -> acc + Enum.count(list, &Map.has_key?(&1, "test")) end)
6
```

Comment: One question, how would it need to be modified if list were instead a list of lists, like [list, list, list] where list = [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}], should I use Map.reduce instead?

Comment: You can pass that to `Enum.concat` before `Enum.count`. You can also use `reduce` if you want. I'll add the code to my answer.

Comment: I have posted my answer mostly as a pun, but now I am thinking it’s even more succinct than `count`/`has_key?` specifically for the case of list of lists.

Comment: @mudasobwa mine should run way faster than yours though. :)

Comment: Why is that? I do not see any reason for it to run faster.

Comment: You're building a huge string one byte at a time while mine is just adding integers.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, exotic answer using [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) comprehension:

```rb
String.length(
  for %{"test" => _} <- [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}],
    do: <<"+">>, into: ""
)
```

---

It’s better extended to the case when we have a list of lists:

```rb
String.length(
  for list <- lists, %{"test" => _} <- list, do: <<"+">>, into: ""
)
```

---

If [`Collectable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Collectable.html) protocol was implemented for `Integer`, it could have been written even in more concise way:

```rb
for %{"test" => _} <- [%{"test" => 1}, %{"test" => 3}, %{"test2" => 1}],
  do: 1, into: 0
```

But unfortunately, it does not :)

Comment: Thanks for your time, good answer, learning more ways to do it.